# Laravel limit, but return more than limit if in the top

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, limit

There is probably some easy way to do this, but I have thought about it for a while and searched and can't seem to find an answer.  I am basically trying to limit the results, but include more than the limit if the proceeding rows past the limit are the same.  For example:

```
Name     Score
John     5
Mike     4
Lucy     3
Sara     3
Thea     2
```

If I wanted to limit the results I would do something like:

```
$topthree = Users::orderBy('score','desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

This would get me the top three results, but how would I also include Sara(from example data), since she also is in the top three scores?

I have considered returning more than I need and doing additional filtering, but I assume there is a better way.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what you accually want?  if you want sara in this list, there is no only top three logic here. so you must have additional logic here.

Comment: Can't you just do it in two steps? 1) get the score of the third one, 2) get all users with a score >= to that.

Comment: You could try to generate a query like: `SELECT Name, Score FROM <table> WHERE Score >= (SELECT Score FROM (SELECT Score FROM <table> ORDER BY Score DESC) <t> LIMIT 2,1);`

Comment: My bad, you don't need to use an alias as in the above example: `SELECT Name, Score FROM <table> WHERE Score >= (SELECT Score FROM <table> LIMIT 2,1);`. This will of course only work if you have atleast 3 records in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using two queries.

First get the 3rd place score:

```
$minScore = Users::orderBy('score','desc')->skip(2)->take(1)->value('score');
```

Then get get all users with at least that score:

```
$topthree = Users::orderBy('score','desc')->where('score', '>=', $minScore)->get();
```

That might also work with a subquery:

```
$minScoreQuery = Users::select('score')->orderBy('score','desc')->skip(2)->take(1);

$topthree = Users::orderBy('score','desc')
    ->where('score', '>=', $minScoreQuery)
    ->get();
```